# Can I view the Unix permissions of a file in a .zip archive?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, permissions

is there a way to view the Unix permissions for a file under Windows?

Comment: Is it even possible to mount a Unix filesystem under windows?

Comment: Yes. http://www.fs-driver.org/ has an implementation of ext2 for windows. Never ran it, wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but it exists.

However, to answer the original question, we need much more information about how the filesystem is being accessed.

Comment: I actually assemble a zip file with the Maven assembly plugin. I set a parameter so that certain directories have certain file permissions. But when I transfer these directories from my Windows computer to our Linux server, the file permissions aren't set as specified. I just take a shortcut and see directly which directory has which file permissions.

Comment: So your question is really "Can I view the permissions of a file in a .zip archive"? If this is the case, edit your original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIRC Zip files created on Windows default to 0777 for directories, and 0666 for files when extracted on a UNIXy system using the Info-ZIP tools.

Zip files created on a UNIXy system using the Info-ZIP tools will preserve the actual UNIX permissions.

Info-ZIP's zipinfo command will display these permissions.

You can find Windows binaries of Info-ZIP's tools on their website (http://www.info-zip.org/) or as part of Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/).

(I'm a former Info-ZIP maintainer for the BeOS and QNX platforms. Long ago. :-))